# Existence of finite endomorphisms on projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, then I wish to obtain some general examples of finite morphisms from $X$ to itself. I know that if $X=\mathbb{P}_k^n$, then we can always consider the maps $$f_d:[x_0:\cdots:x_n]\mapsto[x_0^d:\cdots:x_n^d]$$ for $d\ge1$, interpreted appropriately as a morphism of schemes. However, these maps will in general not take a closed sub variety to itself.

So, is there any wide class of finite endomorphisms over a general projective variety, or do examples only exist on a case by case basis?

Comment: There's multiplication by $n$ on an Abelian variety.

Comment: If $k$ has characteristic $p>0$ and $[k:k^p] < \infty$, then the (absolute) Frobenius morphism is finite.

Comment: Self maps are rare. For a general curve (say genus large), for example, there are no self maps.

Comment: The only other case I can think of is toric varieties (including projective space). Here there is something called the "toric Frobenius" (in any characteristic!) that arises from refining the lattice while keeping the fan fixed.